# Relay mutation error : Expected a record ID in the response payload

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relayjs, relay

I have a Relay Mutation that delete a node in a connection :

```
export default class DeleteDefectMutation extends Relay.Mutation {

    getMutation() {
        return Relay.QL`mutation { deleteDefect }`;
    }

    getVariables() {
        return {
            photoId: this.props.photoId,
            defectId : this.props.defectId
        }
    }

    getFatQuery() {
        return Relay.QL`
            fragment on DeleteDefectMutationPayload {
                updatedPhoto { issues }
                deletedDefectId
            }
        `
    }

    getConfigs() {
        return [{
            type : "NODE_DELETE",
            parentName: 'updatedPhoto',
            parentID: this.props.photoId,
            connectionName: 'issues',
            deletedIDFieldName: 'deletedDefectId'
        }]
    }

    getOptimisticResponse() {
        return {
            deletedDefectId : this.props.defectId,
            updatedPhoto : {
                id : this.props.photoId
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And when I use it with :

```
Relay.Store.commitUpdate(new DeleteDefectMutation({photoId, defectId},{
    onSuccess : () => console.log('Mutation Success !'),
    onFailure : transaction => console.error(transaction.error ? transaction.error : new Error("Mutation Failed"))
}))
```

I get an error that I don't understand :

```
Uncaught Invariant Violation: writeRelayUpdatePayload(): Expected a record ID in the response payload supplied to update the store
```

Comment: `deletedDefectId` returned may be undefined or null. On the GraphQL server side, did you check value of `deletedDefectId` just before returning response?

Comment: In the same if not very similar boat. Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: @jackncoke yes, i was missunderstanding the Relay mutation and it was an error on the server side the deletedDefectId that was not well spelled (in my remind, this is very Old)